# Laravel - document extension validation rule

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a document upload field and I am validate it in laravel using this rule:

`'document' => 'required|mimes:doc,docx,rtf,txt,xls,xlsx,ppt,pdf|max:1536'`

It works fine on the validations. I realized it allowed csv too, I came to know that mime type for csv will be `text` so that's what it allows it. I tried to upload `.sql` that worked too.

What is the best way to have validation based on extension of a document?

Comment: I don't think that validating based on the extension is a very good idea, because i can then upload any type of file with .txt extension, for instance. MimeType actually tries to guess the type.

Comment: @musicvicious, yes then what's the solution, I think .sql files have text mime type which is why they get uploaded easily